# Notepad++, find and replace, convert html to xml tags

Tags: html, regex, xml, notepad++

This is a huge record of mixed html and xml tags which i want to clean.
I want to replace all the html tag into xml ones which i tried but didn't work

**Find:**

```
<tr>
<td class="fid">FID</td>
<td class="fidvalue">(.*)</td>
</tr>
```

**Replace:**

```
<fid>\1<fid>
```

this should replace all similar values in the tags, where were more than 300 occurrences but want to maintain the contents of 'tag' class values

what's the appropriate regex to use?

Comment: Perhaps, `<td\b([^>]*)>(.*?)</td>` -> `<fid\1>\2</fid>`

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something in your question, as Notepad++ (as of v6.9.2) does not have multi-line inputs in its find-and-replace dialog. However, I was able to achieve what you seem to want by specifying those line-breaks manually (and assuming that you want [carriage returns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline));

**Find:** `<tr>\r\n<td class="fid">FID</td>\r\n<td class="fidvalue">(.*)</td>\r\n</tr>`

**Replace:** `<fid>\1</fid>`

Comment: I m using the same notepad version, which i even want to upgrade after a recent prompt, i tried your suggestion with no success

Comment: Perhaps your HTML lines are actually indented? If so, you may need to add `[\s\t]*` where the indentation occurs.

Comment: This answer works fine for me on the string in the question. (1) Make sure that "Regular expression" is selected in the "Replace dialogue". (2) Enable menu **=> View => Show symbol => Show all characters** and check that the `\r`, `\n` and spaces are as expected.